# regex mod_rewrite ?-mark sign causing bug

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect old-style links from an old website to new style links in php.

I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule s\.cfm?id=5$ http://mysite.com/article5.php [B,L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

However, if I use just **s.cfm?**  everything works fine and redirects to article5.php. But if I try to redirect the id=5 part, I get page not found.

I tried just **s.cfm?id**  and it causes the htaccess bug.  So anything you put after question mark ?... causes a problem, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string inside a `RewriteRule`, only the URI path is sent through the rule itself. If you need to match against the query string, then use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var inside a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=5$
RewriteRule ^/?s\.cfm$ http://mysite.com/article5.php [L,R=301]
```

Everything else is fine.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that a bit later. Though I wasn't sure how to write it out. Thanks.